# Usar los operadores lógicos para hacer un sistema de opciones en PHP

Tags: php

Recuerdo que con los operadores lógicos (or, and, not y xor) se podía hacer un sistema de opciones, es decir para determinar si un parámetro/opciónes está compuesto más de uno.

Binariamente seria algo parecido.

bit
1(1) => 0 o 1 para opción 1
2(2) => 0 o 1 para opción 2
3(4) => 0 o 1 para opción 3
.....

es decir si un parametro esta compuesto opcion1 + opcion3 = 1 + 4 = 5

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
define('_OP1_',1);
define('_OP2_',2);
define('_OP3_',4);
define('_OP4_',8);

$parametro = _OP1_ + _OP3_;
```

Me falta construir un par de funciones

`hasParam($parametro,_OP3_)` devuelve `true` o `false` si,la variable `$parametro` contiene la opción `_OP3_`

y la otra función `extractParam($parametro)` y devolviese [2,8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi solución, no ser si hay algo nativo que lo haga:

```
define('_OP1_',1);
define('_OP2_',2);
define('_OP3_',4);
define('_OP4_',8);


$source = _OP3_ | _OP1_ | _OP4_;


if (hasParam($source, _OP1_)) echo '_OP1_ <br />';
if (hasParam($source, _OP2_)) echo '_OP2_ <br />';
if (hasParam($source, _OP3_)) echo '_OP3_ <br />';
if (hasParam($source, _OP4_)) echo '_OP4_ <br />';


print_r(extractParams($source));


function hasParam($param,$opt) {
    return ($param & $opt);

}


function extractParams($param) {
$out = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<$param;$i++) {
        $j = 2 ** $i;


        if (($param & $j)) array_push($out,$j);

    } 
return $out;    


}
```

Me devuelve

```
_OP1_ 
_OP3_ 
_OP4_ 
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 8 )
```